# Java8 stream cannot resolve a variable

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new in Java8 and I want to refactor this piece of code and convert it in a more Java8 style,

```
for (RestaurantAddressee RestaurantAddressee : consultationRestaurant.getAddressees()) {
            Chain chain = chainRestService.getClient().getChainDetails(getTDKUser(), RestaurantAddressee.getChain().getId());
            if (chain.getOrganisation().getId().equalsIgnoreCase(event.getOrganisationId())) {
                chainIds.add(restaurantAddressee.getChain().getId());
            }
        }
```

so I change it for this code:

```
consultationRestaurant.getAddressees()
        .stream()
        .map( ma -> chainRestService.getClient().getChainDetails(getTDKUser(), ma.getChain().getId()))
        .filter(chain -> chain.getOrganisation().getId().equalsIgnoreCase(event.getOrganisationId()))
        .forEach(chainIds.add(chain.getId()));
```

But I have this compilation error:

**chain cannot be resolved**

Comment: `.forEach(chain->chainIds.add(chain.getId()));`

Comment: you could use a collector .collect(Collectors.toList())

Comment: To explain Hadi's comment a bit: the variable declarations in a lambda are only valid for that lambda, i.e. even if you defined `chain` in the lambda you passed to  `filter()` that variable is not visible in `forEach()`.

Comment: Your forEach syntax is wrong, look at the doc. It's way better to use the first snippet than the second one with lots of lambdas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to specify the lambda expression parameter in your `forEach` call.

That said, you shouldn't use `forEach` to add elements to a collection. Use `collect`:

```
List<String> chainIds =
    consultationRestaurant.getAddressees()
        .stream()
        .map( ma -> chainRestService.getClient().getChainDetails(getTDKUser(), ma.getChain().getId()))
        .filter(chain -> chain.getOrganisation().getId().equalsIgnoreCase(event.getOrganisationId()))
        .map(Chain::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here. Your loop defines:

```
Chain chain = chainRestService.getClient()...
```

But your stream statement simply misses to define that variable.

So: in places that **need** that variable, you have to provide, for example as parameter:

```
filter(chain -> chain.getOrganisation().getId().equalsIgnoreCase(event.getOrganisationId()))
```